# why return document.getElementById doesn't work

Tags: javascript

```
var $ = function (id){return document.getElementById(id);}
 window.onload=function(){
 $("num").onfocus=function(){
        $("show").style.display="block";
 }
```

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

but when i change $("num") to $("#num") it can works ,why?

Comment: Do you have jQuery on your page?

Comment: Include some of the html markup too please....

Comment: Why do you think document.getElementById is broken instead of `$` ?

Comment: Can't you see OP try to write own jQuery using `var $ = function (id){return document.getElementById(id);}`?

Comment: Prototype.js library sets $ to document.getElementById, he may have learned the pattern there.

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is jQuery.noConflict. var dom = {};
dom.query = jQuery.noConflict(true);. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: @lukeocom No you can't, because that breaks the context.

Comment: @Kolink, retracted my comment. cheers

Answer (score 2):

You must have jQuery loaded on your page, and you define $ as a local variable, so during the onload the $ variable take it's old signification which is jQuery. And jQuery uses the same selectors as CSS.

You can solve your problem by disabling jQuery if you don't need it, or setting it in compatibility mode, or setting your $ variable as global variable.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works if you

a) do not have jQuery loaded

b) add the missing curly bracket

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/QhxDJ/)

```
var $ = function (id){return document.getElementById(id);} 

window.onload=function(){
   $("num").onfocus=function(){
        $("show").style.display="block";
   }       
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're most probably referencing [uninformative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting) jQuery `$` variable name. And the reason is that both `window.jQuery` and `window.$` are pointing to `jQuery` instance in case of referencing `jQuery` framework [(sources)](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js).

---

In fact, next should work as expected:

```
 window.onload=function(){
   var $ = function (id){return document.getElementById(id);} 
   $("num").onfocus=function(){
        $("show").style.display="block";
   }
 }
```

Comment: Nah. Not the reason at all.

Comment: But you are still blaming scope which is not an issue in this case

Comment: Your code is still missing the closing bracket of the onload function or the onfocus function